# Prolog, Drop Node from Graph

Tags: prolog

i have a problem. I want to drop all link in a graph of a specific node.

Here the code:

```
dropAll(X,[],[]).
dropAll(X,[X|T],L):- dropAll(X,T,L),!.
dropAll(X,[X,H|Xs],[H|L]):- dropAll(X,Xs,L).
dropNode(G,N,O):- dropAll(G,e(N,_),G2),
dropAll(G2,e(_,N),O).
```

But it doesn't work.
I want to obtain this:

Input:

```
dropNode([e(1,2),e(1,3),e(2,3)],1,[e(2,3)]).
```

Output:

```
yes
```

And Input:

```
dropNode([e(1,2),e(1,3),e(2,3)],1,X).
```

Output:

```
X / [e(2,3)]
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I think you could profit from testing smaller units of your code, like dropAll. Do this with more than one example. Additionally, the tracer can help you detect where your code is failing.

Comment: What Prolog is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
dropNode([],_,[]).
dropNode([e(N,_)|T],N,T2):- !, dropNode(T,N,T2).
dropNode([e(_,N)|T],N,T2):- !, dropNode(T,N,T2).
dropNode([H|T],N,[H|T2]):-   dropNode(T,N,T2).
```

In your code, there are several problems:

1. from `dropNode`, you call `dropAll(<InputList>, <Element to drop>, <Resultlist>)`.
   However, that is not the order in your definition of `dropAll`. Thus, calling `dropAll` will fail, since there is no matching clause.
2. Given your usage of it, `dropAll` cannot delete ***different*** nodes matching `e(1,_)` or matching `e(_,1)`. Once it has dropped the first element, `e(1,_)` is unified with that. That is `e(1,2)` in your example and `e(1,3)` doesn't match with it, thus will not be dropped.

Proof: `?- dropAll(e(1,_),[e(1,2), e(1,3)], X).` yields `X = [e(1, 3)]`.

Comment: Nitpick: It is probably better to move the cut "to the left" by one call. Once the head has unified, we can commit to the clause and "cut", then proceed to call dropNode/3 again.

Comment: I absolutely agree since minimizing the stack is always desirable. I edited the solution accordingingly.